# Why isn't ASK (NodeJS) replacing %s with my strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, alexa-skills-kit

I just want to replace these %s with the following strings

```
translation:{
            GREETING : 'What do you want to hear?',
            SKILL_NAME : 'Anime Quotes',
            QUOTE: 'Quote by %s, from %s. %s',   <---
        }
...
outputSpeech = handlerInput.t('QUOTE', character, anime, translated);
```

But when alexa simulator says it she just says %s instead. What am I missing here?

if i try to just make her say these three strings there she does it, but she just wont replace the %s.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research at Alexa Developers Youtube Channel, at the Zero to Hero course I found that an alternative is to use curly brackets at the text field and to fill it like an object. Ex:

QUOTE: 'Quote by {{character}}, from {{anime}}. {{quote}}',
...
outputSpeech = handlerInput.t('QUOTE', {character:character, anime:anime, quote:translated});